# clearTimeout not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
    //Create Account - Register Button
$('#registerCreateAccount').on('click', function() {
    var uid = $('#registerUsername').val();
    var email = $('#registerEmail').val();
    var age = $('#registerAge').val();
    var pwd = $('#registerPassword').val();
    var confirmPwd = $('#registerConfirmPassword').val();
    $.post('./php/register/createAccount.php', {uid: uid, email: email, age: age, pwd: pwd, confirmPwd: confirmPwd}, function(data) {
        if (errTime) {
            clearTimeout(errTime);
        }
        $('.errorMsg').html('<span class="w3-display-middle">' + data + '</span>');
        var errTime = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.errorMsg').html('');
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

So basically what I do is I send data to a PHP file and if there is a callback it will be an error message. So I change the html of the .errMsg div, which was invisible before, because it didn't have any content. Since I only want the error message to be there for 5 seconds I decided to use a setTimeout to clear the content after 5 seconds.

The problem is that when people click the register button multiple times in a row, the setTimeout would keep on going. Because of that, I decided to clear the first timeout when the button is pressed (if it exists), but for some reason it doesn't work.

I've been looking at this for almost an hour and I can't seem to find the bug, thank you guys for helping me out!

**All of you guys are amazing, thanks for helping me so quickly!**

Comment: You need to define `errTime` at a higher scope

Comment: You define the `errTime` variable in your post callback. so every time the function is called it creates a new `errTime` variable. Consider defining the `errTime` variable befor the click event. This way all click handler will access the same `errTime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code scope of the variable ends inside the post callback function make this variable globally available then it will work

```
var errTime;
$('#registerCreateAccount').on('click', function() {
    var uid = $('#registerUsername').val();
    var email = $('#registerEmail').val();
    var age = $('#registerAge').val();
    var pwd = $('#registerPassword').val();
    var confirmPwd = $('#registerConfirmPassword').val();
    $.post('./php/register/createAccount.php', {uid: uid, email: email, age: age, pwd: pwd, confirmPwd: confirmPwd}, function(data) {

            clearTimeout(errTime);

        $('.errorMsg').html('<span class="w3-display-middle">' + data + '</span>');
        errTime = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.errorMsg').html('');
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

scoping issue.

move `var errTime;` above the initial call to `$.post`, so it is not re-defined on each call. Keep `errTime = setTimeout(....)` as it is, but without the `var`.

Comment: Better define it before the `$('#registerCreateAccount').on` since the click event will be called multiple times and triggers only one post request.

Comment: @Bellian, right, if he wants to be able to use errTime more globally. If it's just for this button / functionality, then it's probably better to keep it scoped within the post.

Answer (score 0):

var errTime ist just known in the scope of your timeout function
either define errTime outside globally or inside the $('#registerCreateAccount').on('click', function() {

function where you define uid and so on...

another way is to use window['errTime'] = ....